# Why is the render larger than it should be?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera, world

I've been trying to figure it out for 4 hours and I can't. Has anyone more experienced gone through this?

1. I put a grid image as background in World like this:

[image]

2. In the viewport it is correct as you can see below. My scene/camera has a dimension of 1920×1080.

[image]

3. But when I render, the image is slightly larger than it should be. Why does it happen?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it in many ways but I couldn't figure out where the problem is in my current scene.

I solved the problem by creating a new scene and resetting everything.